# How to handle unresolved props in relay mutations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay

I created a `Relay.Mutation` that should trigger updates on `User` objects:

```
class UserMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
    public getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL`mutation {saveUser}`;
    }

    public getVariables() {
        return {
            id: this.props.user.id,
            loginName: this.props.user.loginName,
            firstName: this.props.user.firstName,
            lastName: this.props.user.lastName,
            mail: this.props.user.mail
        }
    }

    public getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on UserPayload {
                user {
                    id,
                    loginName,
                    firstName,
                    lastName,
                    mail
                }
            }
        `;
    }

    public getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type: "FIELDS_CHANGE",
            fieldIDs: {
                user: this.props.user.id
            }
        }];
    }

    static fragments = {
        user: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on User {
                id,
                // I initially had only id here
                loginName,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                mail
            }
        `
    }
}
```

I'm using this mutation in my component `UserDetails` like this:

```
// I initially passed this.props.user to the mutation
this.props.relay.commitUpdate(new UserMutation({ user: this.state.user })
```

When executing, relay passes a `user` to the backend with only `id` set, without any other property. The mutation is not executed, because the input variable is missing the other fields.

After debugging into the mutation, I saw that `this.props.user` has set `undefined` on all fields but id. However, `this._unresolvedProps.user` is a `user` with all fields set correctly.

When I change the code of the mutation and replace all `this.props` by `this._unresolvedProps`, all necessary data is transmitted to the backend and the mutation is executed without any error. Frontend cache seems to be updated correctly, too (fields like `firstName` are updated in other components). But I don`t expect this to be the right way to go.

What do I miss?

**UPDATE**

The `UserDetails` component loads users data like `loginName` and provides text boxes to change these properties. The corresponding relay container looks like this:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(UserDetails, {
    fragments: {
        user: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on User {
                id,
                loginName,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                mail,
                roles {
                    id,
                    name
                },
                ${UserMutation.getFragment("user")}
            }
        `
    }
});
```

I handle text box changes in a text input handler...

```
public handleTextInput(fieldName: string, event: any) {
    let user = this.state.user;

    switch (fieldName) {
        case "loginName": {
            user.loginName = event.target.value;
            break;
        }
        case "firstName": {
            user.firstName = event.target.value;
            break;
        }
        case "lastName": {
            user.lastName = event.target.value;
            break;
        }
        case "mail": {
            user.mail = event.target.value;
            break;
        }
    }

    this.setState({ user: user });
}
```

...and form submit in a submit handler, where I now pass `this.state.user` to the mutation:

```
public handleSubmit(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.relay.commitUpdate(new UserMutation({ user: this.state.user }), {
        onSuccess: (response: any) => {
            this.setState({ user: response.saveUser.user });
        }
    });
}
```

I use a C# backend: [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet). This is what I have defined for the mutation:

```
public class ApplicationSchema : Schema
{
    public ApplicationSchema()
    {
        this.Query = new ApplicationQuery();
        this.Mutation = new ApplicationMutation();
    }
}

public class ApplicationMutation : ObjectGraphType
{
    public ApplicationMutation()
    {
        this.Name = "Mutation";

        // save a user
        this.Field<UserPayloadType>(
            "saveUser",
             arguments: new QueryArguments(
             new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<UserInputType>>
             {
                 Name = "input",
                 Description = "the user that should be saved"
             }),
            resolve: context =>
                {
                    var userInput = context.Argument<UserInput>("input");
                    var clientMutationId = userInput.ClientMutationId;

                    var user = MemoryRepository.UpdateUser(new User()
                    {
                        Id = userInput.Id,
                        LoginName = userInput.LoginName,
                        FirstName = userInput.FirstName,
                        LastName = userInput.LastName,
                        Mail = userInput.Mail
                    });

                    return new UserPayload()
                    {
                        ClientMutationId = clientMutationId,
                        User = user
                    };
                });
    }
}

public class UserInputType : InputObjectGraphType
{
    public UserInputType()
    {
        this.Name = "UserInput";

        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("id", "The id of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("loginName", "The login name of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("firstName", "The first name of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("lastName", "The last name of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("mail", "The mail adress of the user.");

        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("clientMutationId", "react-relay property.");
    }
}

public class UserPayloadType : ObjectGraphType
{
    public UserPayloadType()
    {
        this.Name = "UserPayload";

        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<UserType>>("user", "The user.");

        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("clientMutationId", "react-relay property.");
    }
}

public class UserType : ObjectGraphType
{
    public UserType()
    {
        this.Name = "User";
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("id", "The id of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("loginName", "The login name of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("firstName", "The first name of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("lastName", "The last name of the user.");
        this.Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("mail", "The mail adress of the user.");

        Field<ListGraphType<RoleType>>("roles", resolve: context => MemoryRepository.GetRolesOfUser(context.Source as DomainModel.Models.User));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your server-side GraphQL mutation `saveUser`? Problem might be with `saveUser`.

Comment: Also, add your Relay container's `fragments` field.

Comment: I just added the required code fragments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Relay container fetching the `User` fragment correctly? I see in your `static fragments` definition fragment on User is only id field, so I wonder if your parent Relay component is fetching them all.

Since your mutation is really dependent on those fields, add them to `fragments` property.

```
class UserMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
    public getMutation() { ... }

    // getVariables, FatQuery and Configs ...

    static fragments = {
      user: () => Relay.QL`
          fragment on User {
              id,
              loginName,
              firstName,
              lastName,
              mail
          }
      `
    }
}
```

And then try including this fragment in Relay component, which uses your mutation.
Example React-Relay component:

```
import UserMutation from 'mutations/user';

class User extends Component {
  commit(e) {
    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new UserMutation({
        user: this.props.user
      })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello</div>
    );
  }
};

export default Relay.createContainer(User, {
  fragments: {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        ${UserMutation.getFragment('user')}
      }
    `,
  }
});
```

Comment: Re: including properties besides id in mutation's `fragments`, dependencies on properties like id (e.g., in `FIELDS_CHANGE` config) and on properties updated in optimistic response must be included in `fragments`. Relay determines which fields to fetch by looking at the fat query. Therefore, if optimistic response is not defined in the mutation, fields except id don't need to be included in fragments.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the code of my parent relay container. I also added all properties like `loginName` etc. to the mutation fragment. Now the user is send to the backend but with unchanged properties ignoring all text input. I added the relevant code fragments in the question. Do I change the user in the right way?

Comment: In the end, I needed to align my schema to be compatible with relay. I am using graphql-dotnet in the backend, where I needed change some of my graph types (like adding all neccessary properties to the users collection etc.). Thanks for your support because listing all properties in the fragment was crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Use **REQUIRED_CHILDREN** and update state in the component.

Rather than use FIELDS_CHANGE you could use REQUIRED_CHILDREN which will enable you to add the returned saved object into your store. What you would do is set up your getConfigs like this:

```
getConfigs() {
  return [{
    type: 'REQUIRED_CHILDREN',
      children: [
        Relay.QL`
          fragment on UserPayload {
            user {
              id
              loginName
              firstName
              lastName
              mail
            }
          }
        `
      ]
  }]
}
```

And in change your commitUpdate like this:

```
this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
  new UserMutation({user: this.props.user}),
  {
    onSuccess: response => this.setState({
      user: response.user,
    }),
    onError: err => console.log(err)
  }
);
```

As you can see, the onSuccess callback enables you to call an actionCreator and put the new user into the state of your application. This you would do using whatever state management you are using in your application. In this case it is simply setState.

> REQUIRED_CHILDREN config is used to append additional children to the mutation query. You may need to use this, for example, to fetch fields on a new object created by the mutation (and which Relay would normally not attempt to fetch because it has not previously fetched anything for that object).
>
> Data fetched as a result of a REQUIRED_CHILDREN config is not written into the client store, but you can add code that processes it in the onSuccess callback that you pass into commitUpdate()

[There is more information in the documentation about REQUIRED_CHILDREN here.](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#required-children)

Comment: Thanks for this hint. But my actual problem is not to get back a `user` but to pass a `user` to the mutation. If I debug into `getVariables()` I see that `this.props.user` just has set the `id`. Thus, when trying to fire the mutation to the backend, I receive `Variable '$input_0' expected value of type 'UserInput'.` because only the `id` is set in the input, but not `firstName`, `lastName` etc.

Comment: Maybe put your mutation on the API up as well? Problem might be there.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the relevant backend code for the mutation.